# How to print the column name with the ratio

Tags: r, dataframe

Example:

```
datname <- c(101,102,103,104)
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(2,4,6,8)
dat <- data.frame(datname,a,b)
```

I would like to find the ratio of each data with datname and save as a new dataframe:

```
with(dat,dat[,2]/dat[,3])
```

I can find the ratio with above, however it does not print out the corresponding datname.

I have tried using [ command and it does not work in this case

```
dat[,1][dat[,2]/dat[,3]]
```

My expected output should be:

```
[1] 101 0.5
[2] 102 0.5
[3] 103 0.5
[4] 104 0.5
```

Comment: `transform(dat, ratio = a/b)`

Comment: `dat$ratio <- dat$a / dat$b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `trasmute` in `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 dat %>%
     transmute(datname, ratio=a/b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `cbind(dat[,1], dat[,2]/dat[,3])`.  See:

```
> cbind(dat[,1], dat[,2]/dat[,3])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  101  0.5
[2,]  102  0.5
[3,]  103  0.5
[4,]  104  0.5
```

Comment: Actually, it does.  The author wrote what does he need, and it provides exactly this.  I changed the wording, because "did you try..." was not an answer grammatically.